# babel-jest doesn't handle ES6 within modules

Tags: babeljs, jestjs, es6-modules

I am trying to set up Jest on a React based project which uses ES6 modules. However I seem to be having issues with ES6 modules, I am using babel-jest and believe I have this set up properly (Jest detects it automatically).

Jest doesn't seem to have a problem using ES6 imports however as soon as it hits on an import statement within one of the imported modules it chokes. It's as if it is only transpiling the initial test script and not any of the imported modules. I have tried various configurations and tried searching Google with no luck. Running tests without any imports works fine.

Here is the error:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import Predications from './predications';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Here are the relevant bits of config:

jest.conf.json

```
{
  "testRegex": "\/test\/spec\/.*\\.js$",
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

Test script

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import Carousel from '../../client/components/carousel/carousel.js'; // test chokes on when I include this module

describe('carousel component', () => {
  it('is a test test case', () => {
    expect(1 + 2).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

**Update:**

As suggested, I have tried running the test without jest.conf.js, however the testRegex is needed in order for Jest to find my tests, I tried moving tests to the default test directory and they still fail.

I would like to clarify that tests themselves are running fine, the issue seems to be where one of my imported modules uses ES6, in my example above, if I don't import my carousel component the test runs fine, as soon as I import that the test chokes on the import statement within that file. It seems as though the imported modules are not getting transpiled.

**Update #2**

After some investigation it appears the issue is that babel is not transpiling ES6 within node_modules. I have created an example repo to demonstrate this here: https://github.com/jamiedust/babel-jest-example

I understand that third party modules should be handling their own transpiling, however we have a number of modules which are hosted on our own npm registry and are re-used between projects, in these cases Webpack handles transpiling, for the Jest tests we need these node_modules to be transpiled by Babel, or a way of leveraging our webpack set up to do this for us.

**Solution**

Add the following config in package.json (or Jest config file).

```
"jest": {
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/(?!test-component).+\\.js$"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the `transform` part form the jest setting. This in not needed in simple cases.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I get the same error, yes your right I don't seem to need it

Comment: have you tried running without `jest.conf.js`? It should work w/o extra configuration

Comment: I suspect `textRegex` and/or `transform` are the origin of the issue

Comment: as you can verify it here https://github.com/MinimalNoise/persist-lead-service, tests pass perfectly on `es-modules` (although *no jsx*) without any particular `jest` configuration

Comment: @Mayas I will try without the jest.conf.js later, however I should have been clear, tests work fine if I don't import any modules

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to use CommonJS just to make tests work right? https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#using-babel
As you can see here, there's no extra configuration you'll need. `babel-polyfill` is needed to make (among others) generators work https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/ but in no means needed for ES Modules

Comment: @Mayas as I understand it Jest does require CommonJS, see the section on Webpack 2 here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html#content. However my setup should be compiling to commonjs modules so shouldn't be an issue. Thanks for your suggestions, but unfortunately they have not helped (see my update in the question).

Comment: Apologies for being quiet Ive been rather busy but am picking this back up now. Please see the update #2 in my original question, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default any code in `node_modules` is ignored by `babel-jest`, see the Jest config option [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string). I've also created a [PR on your example repo](https://github.com/jamiedust/babel-jest-example/pull/1), so you can see it working.

While this works, I've found it to be extremely slow in real applications that have a lot of dependencies containing ES modules. The Jest codebase has a slightly different approach to this as you can find in [babel-jest transforming dependencies](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2034). This can also take much longer on Windows, see [Taking 10 seconds on an empty repo](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1986).

If doing "unit" testing, mocking is probably the better way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had time to check out the PR but I will do. I had tried using a number of Jest options, including, I believe transformIgnorePatterns, however I may have done something wrong so will check it out.

Comment: Finally had a moment to checkout the PR and have accepted, I can now run tests fine. As it happens we have stuck with our Karma/Jasmine stack for the time being. For the benefit of others, the following config worked in resolving this:

`"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!test-component).+\\.js$"
    ]
  },

Comment: @jamiedust If contributors share their opinion probably they might want to sure given information is reached to the other peoples. Removing the repository including relevant PR doesn't help anybody.

Comment: @oyilmaztekin that is a fair point and something I did not consider when deleting that repo, apologies.

Note however that I did put the relevant piece of config in my last comment:

In package.json `"jest": { "transformIgnorePatterns": [ "/node_modules/(?!test-component).+\\.js$" ] }`

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding the transform-es2015-modules-commonjs plugin to your babel config file for testing only. Here is an example config file which tells babel to transpile modules only when in a testing environment. You can put it underneath your presets:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    ["es2015", {"modules": false, "loose": true}]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can read about the plugin here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs

Then, when running your Jest tests on the command line specify NODE_ENV=test (you may need to add the --no-cache flag to the command the first time after making the change to the babel config because Jest caches babel output, but after that you can leave it off:

```
NODE_ENV=test jest --no-cache
```

I learned about this issue in a React seminar by Brian Holt at Frontend Masters. https://frontendmasters.com/courses/

Comment: Thanks @A. Cookro I had previously tried that, just tried it again and no luck, babel seems to be ignoring files in node_modules still.

Comment: After trying 10 other different things, this solution was the only one that behaved properly with ES6 imports

Answer (score 3):

faced the same issue, followed the steps to resolve,

1. install babel-jest
2. in jest config add this configuration

```
       transform: {
           '^.+\\.js?$': require.resolve('babel-jest')
       }
```

3. make sure you have babel.config.js present (your config might be different than provided below)

```
    module.exports = {
      "env": {
        "test": {
          presets: [
            [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              {
                targets: {
                  node: 'current',
                },
              },
            ],
          ]
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem (node_module not transpiled by babel-jest), without being able to solve it.

Instead, I finally succeed by mocking the node_module, like described here https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html

NB: setting mocks in `__mocks__` subfolders did not work for me. So I passed the mock as the second parameter of the `jest.mock()` function. Something like :

```
    jest.mock('your_node_module', () => {})
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution and let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause. Babel now ignores your .babelrc inside node_modules and uses the one provided by the dependency. If you have control of the dependency you would have to add a .babelrc to it and babel would use those settings for it.

this can cause problems though if your dependency and your project use different babel versions or modules.